# Why are some SHA256 hashes longer than 64 characters?

Tags: security, sha256

To my understanding, a SHA256 hash should only be 64 characters long, but I have seen some Indicators of Compromise (IOC) SHA256 hashes which are more than 2000 (2264) characters long. I have tried generating device (Windows) hashes on a few workstations and they are all exactly 4000 characters long.

Why are they are they not 64 characters long?

Why is the IOC SHA256 hash of a different length than the typical device hash?

I am not sure where else to ask this question, if there is a better place/forum, please let me know...

Comment: A SHA256 hash is comprised of 256 **bits** (or 32 bytes) - not characters. There are many ways to represent a sequence of 32 bytes in text, e.g. in Base16 it's 64-characters, and Base64 would be ~43 characters.

Comment: A SHA-256 hash is 32 bytes long. How you decide to represent those 32 bytes is entirely up to you. If you end up needing 2264 characters, then you're either using a very inefficient encoding scheme, or you weren't dealing with a SHA-256 hash to begin with.

Comment: _"but I have seen some Indicators of Compromise (IOC) SHA256 hashes which are more than 2000 (2264) characters long"_ - this statement is nonsensical, it's like saying "I have seen 6-foot-tall people who are 40m in height".

Comment: **Where** are you seeing these _Indicators of Compromise_? Please share a link or similar.

Comment: @Dai I too find it odd that a SHA256 hash is even returning that many characters... But computing the hardware hash via windows powershell (windows autopilot) returns 4000 characters, which I don't get. I get the bit on different bases to represent a sequence of 32 bytes, but not how it returns that many characters for the hash. How the hash was generated: https://www.mobile-mentor.com/insights/how-to-obtain-a-windows-10-hardware-hash-manually-microsoft-intune-windows-autopilot

Comment: @toothpick `Get-WindowsAutoPilotInfo` uses WMI to get `MDM_DevDetail_Ext01`'s `DeviceHardwareData` string. [Microsoft's documentation says "a base64-encoded string of the hardware parameters of a device."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/devdetail-csp#devicehardwaredata) - there's nothing there about it being a SHA-256 hash - so **where** did you get the notion it's a SHA-256 hash specifically?